# How to make a particular sentence bold, large and underlined at the same time

Tags: formatting

I want to make one sentence of a paragraph bold, upper case and underlined at the same time. How do I do that??

For example: `\textbf{}` only makes it bold

Comment: If you find that something which is easy with tools like Word is much harder to do with LaTeX, that's often a sign it's not a good idea in the first place.

Comment: Please think about it once or twice more. You could still add colour and make the chaos perfect ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} 
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\begin{document}
That is from Typographers view a catastrophy: 

\textbf{\uline{\MakeUppercase{That is from Typographers view a catastrophy!}}}

\end{document}
```

[image]